# Why is URLRequest.httpMethod a String?

Tags: swift, foundation

Throughout Foundation, enums are used to configure the behavior of different classes. Calendar, for example, uses Calendar.Identifier to specify what type of calendar an instance is.

For something that's standardized, like HTTP methods, I'm curious why you must supply a prone-to-error string literal to set a URLRequest's method to something other than the default `GET`, like here:

```
func loginUser(requestBody: LoginRequest, completion: @escaping (AuthResult) -> (Void)) {

    var loginRequest = URLRequest(url: "https://foo.com/login")
    loginRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    loginRequest.httpBody = requestBody.toJSONData()

    let loginTask = session.dataTask(with: loginRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // do things...
        completion(result)
    }

    loginTask.resume()
}
```